# How to solve different size of input data for CNN with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build CNN model using TensorFlow at my own data set. But i faced with problem that is i have many pictures with different sizes. There are one kind of object in my pictures. If i make all pictures with same size, objects at pictures are not same size. In order to run CNN model with TensorFlow how to fix this problem? I heard one thing from others that is no matter having different size of input data, using tf.reduce_max, tf.reduce_mean is the best solution. if it is true that best solution to fix my problem, how to use this in my CNN model?

Answer (score 0):

> If i make all pictures with same size, objects at pictures are not same size.

If you know already how to make your input images to have the same size, you are ready for your task to train your CNN model. Unless you have a strict need to make the object for the picture to have the same size, it does not matter to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Usual approach is to resize the images to a fixed size that is accepted by the network as input. This means distorting the aspect ratio of objects.

If that bothers you, you could try padding the images to a square (supposing the network input is a square) and then resize. This will keep the aspect ratio, but add some extra-information (the padding).

Another option is to crop the image to a square, if you are confident you are not losing important information and your task allows it.